# How to throw my own Exception with a pre written method in Java?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I have written my own Exception but I can't throw it.

The application still terminates and gives me the standard error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: H:\db_sort\pdfs\test_5_database
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
at ExceptionTest.filemove(ExceptionTest.java:22)
at ExceptionTest.main(ExceptionTest.java:9)
```

The application has to move some files but it could be that the file that should be moved isn't existing. Then the program shall just print out that the file couldn't be moved and then the program shall move on to the next file.

Here is a piece of my code in which I want to throw the Exception.
The file *test_5_database* isn't existing. Then it shall just print out:

> The File has been renamed, moved or deleted and those changes are not synchronized with the database.

Here is my code (I am not posting my whole code, I will just post my Exception problem):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ExceptionTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      try {
          filemove();
        
          System.out.println("The file has been moved!");
      }
       catch(NoSuchFileException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

    
 }

 private static void filemove() throws IOException, NoSuchFileException{
    Files.move(Paths.get("H:/db_sort/pdfs/test_5_database"),Paths.get("H:/db_sort/pdf s/2019-08/test_5_database"));
 }

}

class NoSuchFileException extends Exception{
    NoSuchFileException(){
        super("The file has been moved, renamed or deleted and those changes 
               are not synchronized with the database");
    }
}
```

I hope that someone can help me and can explain me how I can throw my own Error Message. After displaying the error message the application shall continue with moving files.

Sorry if I made some stupid mistakes in my code, I am quite new to the topic. English is not my mother tongue so please excuse any grammatical or spelling mistakes.
I hope you have a nice day.

Comment: It is thrown. Then you print the stacktrace in your `main` with `e.printStackTrace()`. The program terminates because you're doing nothing after you caught the exception. If you print out something at the end of your main method, you'll notice it gets printed.

Comment: It is thrown. It's also caught. But you should never aspire to throw an Exception from the entry point of your application, you'll never be able to handle the error in a decent way, leading to an unavoidable crash of your application.

Comment: It also seems that you decided to name your exception the same as the exception being thrown. Was that really a good idea? Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

Comment: @Kayaman But I don't get the message _The file has been moved, renamed or deleted and thos e changes are not synchronized with the database."_ The Program just terminates and I dont want that the program terminates because it shall move the next files.

Comment: @Stultuske and how do I fix that in my code? I dont want the application to crash.

Comment: @DavidKrell you make sure your code doesn't crash, by adding catch statements for every Exception that is/can be thrown, and don't add "throws ....Exception" to the  signature of the main method

Comment: Do you realize the exception that's being thrown is `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` and you named your exception `NoSuchFileException`? Did you think that since they have the same name, your exception would somehow be substituted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Files.move(...)` throws a `NoSuchFileException` which comes from the package `java.nio.file`.

Your implementation of `NoSuchFileException` may have the same name, but it is never thrown. So you have to `catch` the `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` and throw your own `my.package.NoSuchFileException`.

But maybe it is best (to avoid all confusion) to rename your Exception in for example `FileNotSynchronizedException`. You could do it like this:

**First option** (you may want to remove the imports for NoSuchFileException)

```
private static void filemove() throws IOException, NoSuchFileException{
     try{
        Files.move( Paths.get("H:/db_sort/pdfs/test_5_database"),Paths.get("H:/db_sort/pdf s/2019-08/test_5_database"));
     }catch(java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException e){
         throw new my.package.NoSuchFileException();
     }
}
```

**Second Option**

```
private static void filemove() throws IOException, FileNotSynchronizedException{
     try{
        Files.move( Paths.get("H:/db_sort/pdfs/test_5_database"),Paths.get("H:/db_sort/pdf s/2019-08/test_5_database"));
     }catch(NoSuchFileException e){
         throw new my.package.FileNotSynchronizedException();
     }
}
```

See the the different `throws` clause in the method header? You simply changed the Exception by throwing your own.

IMHO the second option is better, you would avoid conflicts with the existing Exceptions from  `java.nio.files` and it gives you the opportunity to make more specific exceptions. For example if you want to catch the IOException as well and throw your own, then just add another catch clause.

Comment: I tried it and it works, but how can I rewrite my program, that it continues with moving files? For example: the _test_5_database_ isnt existint. Then it prints out my exception, which is working now. Now the application shall move on to the next file for example _test_6_database. This file is existing and it shall be moved again. With the same method `File.move(...)`. How can I do that?

Comment: I guess that is a different kind of problem. In your example code you don't pass any parameter (like the Filename) to your `filemove()` method. What if you where to pass the filename as a parameter:`filemove(String filename)` and then iterate over all your files.  And inside your iteration / loop where you call the `filemove` method you put your `try-catch` block that catches your Exceptions, logs them and then continues with the loop. `for(String file: myFiles){ try{ filemove(file);}catch(MyExceptions e){Logger.getLogger.....}}`

Comment: Hey, how exactly can I do that? I have written something and it gives me no error but its not moving my files. Here is my code:                                                           
 `private static void filemove(String path,String timestamp,String filename) throws IOException, FileNotSynchronizedException{
  File[] files =new File(path+timestamp).listFiles();
  for(File file:files) {
   try{
    Files.move(Paths.get(path+filename),Paths.get(path+timestamp+"/"+filename));
   }catch(NoSuchFileException e) {
    throw new FileNotSynchronizedException();
    
    }
  }

 }`

Comment: Please open a new Question with this new problem, so that other SO users can help you too. Don't forget to paste the code of your `filemove` method and the code that calls this method.

Comment: I already solved the problem, but thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you create new exception give it name different from the existing one.

To thorow exception you should write:

```
throw new ExceptionName("message");
```

for example:

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
```

If you want to throw exception when file does not exist:

```
if(checkIfFileExists) {
    throw new ExceptionName("message");
}
```

before you perform operation.

In your case the best approach is to change catch (creating new exception is unnecessary in that case), for example:

```
   catch(NoSuchFileException e) {
       System.out.println("The file has been moved, renamed or deleted and those 
       changes are not synchronized with the database");
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can throw a custom exception like below, hope my understanding is correct.

package test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ExceptionTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFileException {
      try {
          filemove();

          System.out.println("The file has been moved!");
      }
       catch(IOException e) {
           throw new NoSuchFileException();
       }


 }

 private static void filemove() throws IOException{
        Files.move(Paths.get("H:/db_sort/pdfs/test_5_database"),Paths.get("H:/db_sort/pdf s/2019-08/test_5_database"));
 }

}

class NoSuchFileException extends Exception{
    NoSuchFileException(){
        super("The file has been moved, renamed or deleted and those changes are not synchronized with the database");
    }
}

Output : 
Exception in thread "main" test.NoSuchFileException: The file has been moved, renamed or deleted and those changes are not synchronized with the database
    at test.ExceptionTest.main(ExceptionTest.java:15)
```